# jQuery ajax failing only in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, frontend

Ran into an issue that has stumped me for 2 days now. I use codeigniter for my backend and jquery for my front end. Almost all my controller functions are loaded via jquery $.ajax without any issues, until yesterday.

For some random reason whenever I perform an ajax query on my controller named "advertising", it fails, yet if I literally copy/paste the same ajax query and only change the url to another controller, it works fine. The issue is only occuring in chrome, and the same query works fine in firefox and ie.

Here is the code:

```
$("a").on("click", function(a){
  a.preventDefault();
  var path = $(this).attr("href");

  $.ajax({
    Type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    url: path,
    success:function(result){
      $(".contentgrid").hide().html(result).fadeIn("fast");
    }
  })
})
```

This throws the following error in chrome:

```
send                   jquery.min.js:2 
v.extend.ajax          jquery.min.js:2 
(anonymous function)   main.js:743 
v.event.dispatch       jquery.min.js:2 
o.handle.u
```

Yet if I paste the ajax request above and manually type some other controller/function name, it works correctly. If manually type the controller named "advertising" it fails. Again, this works perfectly fine in both IE and Firefox. I'm totally lost. Thanks for anyone who can give me a hand.

Comment: It's actually `type`, with a lowercase `t`, and case matters, even if `GET` is the default method.

Comment: Changed it to:  type: "get" and I'm still getting an error. Thank you though, let me know if you have any other ideas. :)

Comment: The `path` is of course an url to the same domain.

Comment: Yes. The href is "/advertising/dashboard".

The bizarre part is that if I simply make the href = "/advertising". It will correctly load the index() function in my advertising controlloer, but as soon as I add another controller name, it fails. Every piece of code I change to make it work, I retest in other browsers and it works fine in those.

Comment: Also, if I go directly to the controller url without performing an ajax request, it works fine.

Comment: 1. Try using a developer version of jQuery, the one that's not minified. That way, you won't be getting some "line 2" error which makes no sense. 2. Check the response of your server on the Network Tab. It might not be an issue of your JS, but something else. 3. When developing front-end, make sure "Disable Cache" is checked, so that you are not using stale code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't post the fix. The reason this wasn't working was because the "AdBlocker" extension blocks anything with "advertising" in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the HTML isn't perfectly valid - try using `.text()` instead of `.html()` to check out what happens, and if it works, fix the invalid HTML.